# Predicate for has triplicate in a list?

Tags: prolog

I am writing a predicate to print true if a list contains 3 copies of an element and also to print the element. Also the predicate should print alternate solutions if they exist.

The predicate which I have written -

```
hasTriplicate(List):-hasTriplicateAcc(List,Element,0).

%hasTriplicateAcc is wrapped by predicate hasTriplicate since I wanted the arity of hasTriplicate to be 1.

hasTriplicateAcc(_,Element,3):-write(Element).
hasTriplicateAcc([H|T],H,Ct):-hasTriplicateAcc(T,H,Ct1),Ct1 is Ct+1.
hasTriplicateAcc([Z|T],H,Ct):-hasTriplicateAcc(T,H,Ct),Z=\=H.
```

The output

```
hasTriplicate([1,1,1]).
11
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] 3 is _10188+1
ERROR:   [10] hasTriplicateAcc([1,1],1,_10218) at c:/users/user/desktop/code/hastriplicate.pl:3
ERROR:    [9] hasTriplicateAcc([1,1|...],1,0) at c:/users/user/desktop/code/hastriplicate.pl:3
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
Exception: (10) hasTriplicateAcc([1, 1], 1, _10332)
```

I don't understand the error. It would be good if anyone tells me how to correct my code for the predicate.

Comment: A couple of notes, not necessarily related to your error. Firstly, the `=\=` operator requires that the arguments be numeric since it's a numeric expression comparator. I'm not sure if that's your intention (you didn't say whether your predicate requires lists of numbers only). Also, your first predicate clause, `hasTriplicate(List):-hasTriplicateAcc(List,Element,0).` has a singleton warning I assume you saw indicating that `Element` is singleton, meaning that it only appears once and doesn't serve a purpose as a named variable.

Comment: One thing you can do is a `trace` (enter `trace.`) then run your query again. It will take you step by step through the execution of your query.

Comment: Your problem is probably centered here: `hasTriplicateAcc([H|T],H,Ct):-hasTriplicateAcc(T,H,Ct1),Ct1 is Ct+1.` When you call `hasTriplicateAcc(T,H,Ct1)` here, `Ct1` is not instantiated. Inside that call, an attempt is made to compute `Ct1 is Ct+1` where the uninstantiated `Ct1` is what was unified with the `Ct` argument in the recursive query. So you are attempting to perform arithmetic on an uninstantiated argument.

Comment: @lurker Yes, I put `Ct1 is Ct+1` before `hasTriplicate(T,H,Ct1)` and then it worked fine. Also, the list can contain any item including alphanumeric elements.

Comment: If you want to allow alphanumeric elements, then you cannot use `=\=` since it's for numeric expressions. Try using `\==` instead.

Comment: @lurker How do I enter `trace` and what is `trace` ? Can you please provide any relevant link. Thanks!!

Comment: Would \== work for numeric as well as alphabets ?

Comment: `\==` will work with any kind of atom or numeric. `trace` does what it says: it traces the execution of your query. As I mentioned in my prior comment, you enter `trace.` at the prompt. With each subsequent query prompt, press Enter for the next statement.

Comment: You'll also want to do your `write` after you've proven that there are 3 duplicates. Your current solution will print a given element multiple times. In Prolog, though, it's generally better to use another query argument to hold the solution rather than `write` to the display. Prolog then displays your results as a solution rather than a write output. The analogy would be if you were asked to write a function in C to compute the square of a number, you would have the function return the value. You would not have the function `printf` the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution will work .

```
hascountminimal(_,_,0):-true,!.
hascountminimal([E|L],E,N):- ! , N1 is N - 1 , N >= 1 , hascountminimal(L,E,N1) .
hascountminimal([_|L],E,N):- hascountminimal(L,E,N).


intripple(L,E):-hascountminimal(L,E,3),write(E).
```